# Can't open Python encoded URL containing Cyrillic symbols

Tags: python, url, encoding

I have the following URL "mysite.com/\u0422\u0435\u043A\u0441\u0442 \u043D\u0430 \u043A\u0438\u0440\u0438\u043B\u0438\u0446\u0430" ("mysite.com/Текст на кирилица"). I want to open this URL using browser.open(link) where browser is

```
$CHandler = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar())
browser = urllib2.build_opener(CHandler)
user_agent = '  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110420 Firefox/3.6.17'
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', user_agent )]
urllib2.install_opener(browser)
```

However I get the error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 12-17: ordinal not in range(128)"

I get this URL from JSON.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mysite.com/Текст на кирилица` is not a URL:

- because it has omitted the `http://` (or other) schema;
- it has spaces in, which aren't valid;
- because [URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) can't contain non-ASCII characters. Only [IRIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier) can, and `urllib2` doesn't support them.

So you will need to fix the brokennesses, %-encoding out of band characters (like space -> `%20`), add the schema if missing, and then convert IRI to URI. To do this conversion you will need to encode the hostname part of the address using the [IDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) algorithm (Python: `s.encode('idna')`), then encode any non-ASCII characters in other parts of the address using UTF-8 then %-encoding.

What you want to end up with is:

```
http://mysite.com/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0
```

which is a valid URI accepted by `urllib2`, but also displays as `http://mysite.com/Текст на кирилица` in the browser's address bar when you follow it.

There are lots of functions about that implement IRI-to-URI (most Python web frameworks have something like it, for one). If you want to go the whole hog on correcting and normalising suspect incoming URLs, there's also [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/urlnorm).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the idea but i can't get it to work. `import urllib s = '\u0422\u0435\u043A\u0441\u0442\u043D\u0430\u043A\u0438\u0440\u0438\u043B\u0438\‌​u0446\u0430'  s = s.encode('UTF-8') print s print urllib.urlencode(s)` And I'm getting an error "TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object"

Comment: `s` is a byte string so your `\u` sequences aren't doing anything. Use `u'\u0422...'` to get a Unicode string on which you can call `encode('utf-8')`. Then the URL-encoding function you want is `urlquote()`. `urlencode()` takes a mapping of keys and values from which to create a query string, which is not what you want here.

Comment: This did the job for me:
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib
s = unicode('\u0422\u0435\u043A\u0441\u0442\u043D\u0430\u043A\u0438\u0440\u0438\u043B\u0438\‌​‌​u0446\u0430', errors='ignore')
s = s.encode('utf-8')
print urllib.quote(s)`
@bobince Thank you!